# Rails - using :include to find objects based on their child's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a sentence and correction model

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :correction

class Correction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sentence
```

and I'm trying find all sentences which don't have a correction. To do this I'm simply looking for corrections which don't exist i.e. whose id = nil. But it is failing and i can't figure out why

```
 Sentence.find :all, :include => :correction, :conditions => {:correction => {:id => nil}}

from (irb):4>> Sentence.find :all, :include => :correction, :conditions => {:correction => {:id => nil}}
```

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'correction.sentence_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `sentences` WHERE (`correction`.`sentence_id` IS NULL)

Perhaps its the syntax or maybe just the overall approach. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Sentence.all(:include => :correction, 
  :conditions => "corrections.sentence_id IS NULL")
```

Comment: the problem is im getting this error

Sentence.all(:include => :correction, 
?>   :conditions => "corrections.sentence_id IS NULL")
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'correction.sentence_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `sentences` WHERE (`correction`.`sentence_id` IS NULL)

Comment: It looks like you are referring `correction` instead of `corrections` in `conditons` string.